# How do i resize dynamically a window in kivy?

Tags: python, window, kivy, size

I had a problem during a desktop app construction because in different screens I need a different window size(like login, menus, etc)
what do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the window size in the screens [`on_pre_enter`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.Screen) event. Its probably best to have no transition when changing window size while switching screen.
Try this example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder


KV = """
#:import Window kivy.core.window.Window
#:import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition

ScreenManager:
    transition: NoTransition()
    Screen:
        on_pre_enter:
            Window.size = (400, 400)
        name: "scr1"
        Button:
            font_size: "40sp"
            text: "Next screen"
            on_release:
                root.current = "scr2"
    Screen:
        on_pre_enter:
            Window.size = (200, 50)
        name: "scr2"
        Button:
            font_size: "20sp"
            text: "Previous screen"
            on_release:
                root.current = "scr1"

"""


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

MyApp().run()
```

Comment: You are wellcome